# <p> tag within a <div> tag font-weight

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am having issues with a large font size and weight fitting in a div tag.
I want it vertical-align bottom, so please help me.

```css
div
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
  
}

table
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

p 
{
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:900;  
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

td
{
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:900;  
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>TEST</p> 
</div>

<hr>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have included a demonstration of what I can do with a  but I want a div tag to do the same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9m6umvd/3/

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? `vertical-align` does not work on block level elements like paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you looking for exactly , but `margin-top` could be an option here to position your text

http://jsfiddle.net/t9m6umvd/2/

and this : jsfiddle.net/t9m6umvd/5

you can also try the top:0; with `relative/absolute` positioning.
like this:

```
div
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;

}

p 
{
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:900;  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9m6umvd/4/

Comment: Is there a way to by default allow it to vertical-align bottom? I don't want to set margins for each element with a different font size, weight in different height boxes. sorry to be a pain.

Comment: for that you can use well focused css selectors, then you will be able to focus on a particular element on the page.

Comment: You can use `position: relative` on parent `div` and `position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;` for p tag.

Comment: the position options don't seem to work. I have updated the snippet to demonstrate the differences between a <table> and a <div>. I want the <div> to operate the same way as the <table>

Comment: try margin-top   margin-top:25px;